# Strange behaviour of vector in cpp

Tags: c++, vector

I was writing the naive version of the polynomial multiplication algorithm. I tried the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> multp(const vector<int>& A, const vector<int>& B) {
    vector<int> result = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size() + B.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++) {
            result[i + j] += A[i] * B[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main () {
    vector<int> A = {1, 1};
    vector<int> B = {1, 1, 1};
    vector<int> result = multp(A, B);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << result[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it worked just fine, but then, I changed the initialization of the vector from `vector<int> result = {0};` to only `vector<int> result;`. Here I got a seg fault! Why is that? What difference does the  `= {0}` make?

Also, in main, after the line `vector<int> result = multp(A, B);`, when I tried to print the length of the vector (`cout << result.size() << endl;`) I got 1 even tho the vector had 4 elements in it. Why does this happen?

Comment: Both versions are Undefined Behaviour. `vector<int> result` creates vector that stores exactly 0 numbers, `vector<int> result = {0};` creates vector that stores exactly 1 number. If one of them "works", it's by sheer misfortune.

Comment: Instead of `result[i] = 0;` try using `result.push_back(0);` to append an integer zero to your vector. This will give it the correct number of elements.

Comment: Or better, remove the useless loop and initialize vector with correct number of elements: `vector<int> result = std::vector<int> (A.size() + B.size());`

Comment: *And it worked just fine* - [no, it really didn't work "just fine"](https://godbolt.org/z/djo18M9ov).

Comment: Change this: `result[i] = 0;` to this: `result.at(i) = 0;`.  You will see it no longer "works", and instead, throws an `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: *And it worked just fine,* -- "I used a rope that is rated to hold 500 pounds to hold up an item that weighs 600 pounds.  It worked just fine..." -- That's basically what happened -- the rope may hold up "just fine", it may break tomorrow, may never break, or if your friend bought the same brand of rope, break immediately when they try to hold up 600 pounds with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<int> result = {0};` creates a `vector` with one element so you aren't allowed to access anything but `result[0]`. An alternative would be to create the vector with as many elements that you need, `A.size() + B.size() - 1`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> multp(const std::vector<int>& A, const std::vector<int>& B) {
    std::vector<int> result(A.size() + B.size() - 1); // correct size

    /* this is not needed, they will be 0 by default
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size() + B.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = 0;
    }
    */

    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < B.size(); j++) {
            result[i + j] += A[i] * B[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {1, 1};
    std::vector<int> B = {1, 1, 1};
    std::vector<int> result = multp(A, B);

    for(int resval : result) {        // a convenient range based for-loop
        std::cout << resval << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify or access array elements that don't exist. When you create an empty vector, it has no elements you can modify or access.

```
vector<int> result = {0}; // creates vector with one entry
for(int i = 0; i < A.size() + B.size(); i++) {
    result[i] = 0; // legal only when i==0
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Instead of doing `result[i] = 0` I should've used `result.push_back(0)`.